# Create a lambda expression from a List of objects

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

I'm trying to implement a multi-select filter to pass to a generic repository.

The repository filter method takes an `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` parameter.

Generally I would apply the filter as 
`Filter(i => i.Id == myId && i.Name.Contains(myName))` but in this case I have a set of values that are provided in a List and I want to iterate through the list and dynamically create part of the Lambda expression to pass to the Filter method.

So my call to the filter method would be something like Filter(myGeneratedLambdaExpression && i.Name.Contains(myName))

where myGeneratedLambdaExpression would then resolve to something like
(i => i.Id == myId1 || i.Id == myId2 || i.Id == myId3) and myId1, myId2 and myId3 are the values contained in a List

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Take a look at [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Are you asking about the specific scenario listed here (||ing a bunch of == conditions), or are you talking about a general way of doing this for other scenarios?

Comment: For now the specific scenario. If I can get a start I can probably work out a generic solution if necessary

Comment: Bobson - Thanks, that looks like just what I need

Answer (score 0):

You need [DynamicLinQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-DE/vstudio/bb894665.aspx). See [this](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) blog.